# Repacked packing nut but sink is still leaking!

Tags: plumbing, leak, faucet

I have a leaky cold water valve in my laundry room. It is a gate valve with a similar set up to [This post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/47903/what-are-my-options-for-fixing-a-laundry-faucet/47906#47906) (although older and with a lot of scaling). I did some research and decided to buy some 5/32 inch valve packing to re-pack the valve. I cleaned the old packing out, scraped the scaling off of the nut, wrapped the packing around the stem 2 times and tightened the nut down until it stopped leaking. I then decided to test it with a load of laundry. Of course, at this point it started leaking slowly again.

This has led me to a question which I haven't been able to find the answer to online:

The valve leaked whether it was open, closed or somewhere in between. Does this suggest that the issue is related to the washer or o-ring located at the bottom of the stem rather than the packing nut itself?

I'd hate to call a plumber, only to learn that I hadn't packed the nut properly but replacing the stem is above my pay grade. Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the cutoff valve for the cold water supply to the washing machine? Does it take several turns to go from closed to full open on the stop?

If, when the valve is closed, it leaks continuously around the stem, then the plastic washer at the bottom of the stem needs replacing. One has to remove the stem to do this. Some of the valves of this type use the packing nut to cover the interior and other valves have a separate screw cover. These latter can be stuck in place, but if not stuck this is a standard maintenance procedure.

With the stem out to change the washer, one inspects the brass seat in the valve body. If the sealing surface is compromised, then it should be replaced. However, a valve in cut-off service for a washing machine is hardly ever cycled so the seat is probably OK.

Comment: It would not be the o-ring/washer at the bottom of the valve if it leaks when open. The washer is the sealing portion of the valve and would only be an issue if it leaked when closed. If it leaks when closed, then yes that washer is bad. If it leaks no matter the position, you have a bad seal on the nut end.

Comment: Yes this is the cold water valve to the washing machine and it takes several turns to go from fully open to fully closed. Now that I have replaced the packing inside the nut, it's not leaking while closed but it's still leaking while opened. Do you think that means that the stem needs replacing or is it more likely that I didn't put enough packing material inside the nut? I wrapped the 5/32 valve packing around the stem twice before tightening the bolt down. I can't tighten the nut any more than it already is but it still leaks while the valve is open.

Comment: I think you should add more packing or redo the packing and put more packing than you did the first time. You say now that it is NOT leaking while closed. This means that the rubber washer seal is OK and it is leaking around the packing on the stem. The first thing to do is to try to stop the leak by twisting the valve harder open (but not too hard) to press against the packing. That prolly won't stop it and you will have to repack it. If you can't tighten the packing nut further, then you didn't put on enough packing.

Comment: Just looked at the picture you referenced. If your valve is that same as that, then the bonnet nut (which you have already taken off) is all that needs to come off to remove the stem. Note that tightening the bonnet nut should **not** be done with the valve all the way open, but with it part way closed or fully closed. To remove the stem, take the bonnet nut off and just keep opening the valve more and more open and it will unscrew out. If the old packing is still there it will come out with the stem. If you take this to a plumbing supply they can sell you a washer and maybe formed packing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The valve in the picture looks different than the one I have. That picture was meant to show the setup of hot,cold and drain pipe, although that may have been redundant. I'm going to try to pull the stem out Friday. If it's stuck in the valve I'll just add more packing and hope for the best.

Comment: One last question: Should I take the packing that's already in there out and discard it or can I just add more on top of the new stuff I already added?

Comment: The valve in the picture is threaded on, and the whole valve replaced by unscrewing with wrenches. But a lot of times the valves are sweated on (i.e., soldered with a torch) because if done right this makes a leak free connection. A couple of years ago I replaced the original sweated on valves for our washer with ball valves. I sweated on fittings (1/2" F-tube to 1/2" FIP) so I could just screw in valves if I had to replace them. When I did screw them in with Teflon tape I had leak through threads. Took off and redid with pipe dope, but still a v slow *seep*. After a week the seep stopped.

Comment: I don't know if you could just add more or if it's better to entirely replace it so  that it's all one piece. Did you first try to open the valve firmly against the stop? Did you tighten the bonnet nut with the valve partly closed?

Comment: If you have a lot of mineral deposits on the stem, you might have to remove them to get it to seal. I'd use vinegar and a Scotchbrite pad. You'd have to remove the stem to do this. But be careful not to make longitudinal scratches on the stem. Best to use the Scotchbrite blue wavy, the green rectangular has alumina particles and will scratch.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, as you have probably gathered I've never done any plumbing work before. I stepped away for dinner and now it's leaking even though I have the valve closed. I'm guessing this means I need to pull the stem up, correct? I'm not sure what opening the valve firmly against the stop means. As for the other question I tightened the nut while the valve was fully closed.

Comment: The washer supply hose is slightly elastic and will get pressurized when the valve is open and so that when you close the valve water could flow back from the hose and out around the stem. It still may be the case that all you need to do is to repack the stem packing.

Comment: Opening the valve up firmly against the stop means to keep turning the valve as it opens until you can turn it no further and then give a little more force even though it won't move much or at all. This clamps the expanded part of the stem against the packing and compresses it around the stem. There is a term for this "backseating the valve" and is the way these valves are kept from leaking in the open position.  These valves should be either closed snugly (but not wrenched hard) or fully open and backseated. Do not leave it partially open. It may leak in the half open position and that's OK.

Comment: If and when you decide to replace the valves, as far as I know most people are using ball valves for washing machine cut-off valves. Generally ball valves are kept fully closed or fully open, they are not used for controlling flow in a continuous range. The advantage of ball valves is that they will generally work dependably even after being left open or left closed for years. For example, ball valves are now usually used for main cut-off valves to the house, for hot water heater cut-off, and for the cut-off valves for sinks, lavatories, and toilets. Ball valves do not need to be backseated.

Comment: Any new report on the leaking on this valve?

Comment: I wasn't able to work on the valve again until today. I pulled the nut off again, cleaned the threads and stem with white vinegar and repacked the nut. While I had the packing nut off, I tried to pull the stem out but the whole valve wanted to turn. Even with channel locks on the valve I couldn't break the seal. I didn't want to apply too much force for fear of breaking the pipe behind the drywall. In the open position it is now only a very slow seep.

Comment: You can't pull the stem out, it should unscrew, **IF** you have removed the bonnet. Some valves have two 'nuts' on top--one is the packing nut and one is what I would call the bonnet nut. In valves with this arrangement the packing nut is smaller and the enlarged inside part of the stem will not come out through the hole the shaft of the stem goes through. One has to remove the larger 'bonnet' nut. What does your valve have?

Comment: See here https://www.google.com/search?q=water+valve+with+and+without+separate+packing+nut&biw=1094&bih=487&tbm=isch&imgil=Kf_Kr0MaN-6WpM%253A%253BGhJUKmPP5kbKsM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fgeorgebrazilplumbingelectrical.com%25252Fblog%25252Fwhy-is-my-main-water-shut-off-valve-leaking-a-phoenix-plumber-explains&source=iu&pf=m&fir=Kf_Kr0MaN-6WpM%253A%252CGhJUKmPP5kbKsM%252C_&usg=__C8Qouz2Dn6RLf8ZfpbvLClRWGKQ%3D&ved=0ahUKEwjrhrjB0vzRAhUIrVQKHavNDk8QyjcILw&ei=bgmZWOuXLYja0gKrm7v4BA#imgrc=Kf_Kr0MaN-6WpM:

Comment: Mine had a separate packing nut. The stem has a hexagon below the threads that you tighten the packing nut onto just like the one in the link you posted. It looks to me like if you loosen the hex it should pull the stem out of the valve for replacement. My issue was that even with channel locks holding the valve in place I couldn't break the seal between the stem and the valve. I didn't want to put too much torque on the copper pipes below the valve for fear of breaking them.

Comment: If you loosen (i.e., untighten) the bonnet nut, it does NOT pull the stem out. You must completely unthread (unscrew) the larger hex nut so it is LOOSE. Then you turn the handle on the stem and it unscrews out.

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant: unscrewing the hex nut. The nut was really stuck on there though. Whenever I tried to turn the nut with the wrench the channel locks wanted to move with it. I stopped because i'm not sure how much torque it takes to bust the pipe below and I didn't want to find out. I think I'm going to buy a pipe wrench and try again.

Comment: If it is really tight, you might not be able to get it off. The only solution might be replacement of the entire valve. Is the valve sweated on (that is soldered) to copper tubing or is it attached by another means--threaded on, compression . . . If you can get the valve off, you could perhaps get the bonnet loose by putting the valve in a vise or holding it in a better position. What kind of water supply pipes do you have?

Comment: I can't tell exactly how the valve is attached to the pipes; that's all done behind drywall. I've been watching videos and replacing the valves doesn't seem too involved. I think the required parts and tools may only cost me about $50 total. I was debating between using a sharkbite fitting or having the soldering done by a contractor. Everything else seems within my capability. Do you have any opinions on this? Also, thank you for all of your help.

Comment: I have never used Sharkbite but there are good reports on them. If the valve is sweated in you will need a torch to melt the solder and pull it off. If you have never done this I must warn you that yu can catch the house on fire! A friend of mine who is a retired general contractor and all round expert started a fire in his house with a soldering torch and just barely got it out before it went out of control.  I cannot recommend your doing this if you have never done it. Call a plumber and tell him you want replacement of your supply valves to washer with modern ball valves an  get an estimate

Comment: Is your piping coming horizontally out of the wall or (like mine) vertically into a box in the wall behind the washer?

Comment: The piping is vertically fed into a box. I'm not doing any soldering for that reason. I have no business operating a propane torch near flammable materials!

Comment: In my box the joint at the bottom of the valve is visible and far enough above the bottom ot the box that I was able to heat the old valve, melt the solder, and pull off the old valve. Then I soldered on a fitting 1/2" female tubing to 1/2" FIP. Are you saying that the bottom of your valve is inside the wall and so inaccessible to you? And you don't even know how the valve is attached? It might be a screw fitting or it might be sweated on. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: I can't tell for certain. There's an o-ring that creates a seal between the bottom of the valve and the plastic housing. That makes me think it's screwed on. I'll have to cut into the drywall to know for certain though.

Comment: You can get plastic inspection panels in various sizes. Get one say 9" x 12" and cut a hole so that will fit. Then you will have a permanent and convenient way to inspect the pipe. This will allow you to work on it. If it is copper tubing you could cut off the tubing and splice in a new piece of tubing to get the valve higher in the box. You could do this with no torch and use Sharkbite fittings.

Comment: Yes that's almost exactly what my plan was down to the inspection door. I'd seen a lot of videos and it seemed to be straightforward using sharkbites, although I'm sure Murphy's law will beg to differ.

Comment: Are these water lines copper tubing?

Comment: I won't know until I cut into the drywall. I can't see them.

Comment: Almost certainly you have the same piping throughout. What is the piping where you can see it? Look under the kitchen sink, bathroom lavatory, behind toilet.